# Why do you need SpinWait in LockFreeUpdate sample from Albahari's "Threading in C#"

Tags: c#, multithreading, lock-free, optimistic-concurrency, spinwait

I am working on small `Ref<T>` abstraction with lock-free optimistic Update method (supposed to work with immutable `T` data structures, immutable trees in particular).
It is based on Albahari's "Threading in C#" `LockFreeUpdate` method in [SpinWait usage](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part5.aspx#_SpinWait) section:

```
static void LockFreeUpdate<T> (ref T field, Func <T, T> updateFunction) where T : class
{
  var spinWait = new SpinWait();
  while (true)
  {
    T snapshot1 = field;
    T calc = updateFunction (snapshot1);
    T snapshot2 = Interlocked.CompareExchange (ref field, calc, snapshot1);
    if (snapshot1 == snapshot2) return;
    spinWait.SpinOnce();
  }
}
```

**My question is Why do we need SpinWait here?**
Because if field is already updated then another concurrent code can immediately retry to Update from new value.

Full Ref code without SpinWait is provided below (check `Update` method for comparison):

```
public sealed class Ref<T> where T : class
{
    public T Value { get { return _value; } }

    public Ref(T initialValue = default(T))
    {
        _value = initialValue;
    }

    public T Update(Func<T, T> update)
    {
        var retryCount = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            var oldValue = _value;
            var newValue = update(oldValue);
            if (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _value, newValue, oldValue) == oldValue)
                return oldValue;
            if (++retryCount > RETRY_COUNT_UNTIL_THROW)
                throw new InvalidOperationException(ERROR_EXCEEDED_RETRY_COUNT);
        }
    }

    private T _value;

    private const int RETRY_COUNT_UNTIL_THROW = 10;
    private static readonly string ERROR_EXCEEDED_RETRY_COUNT =
        "Ref retried to Update for " + RETRY_COUNT_UNTIL_THROW + " times But there is always someone else intervened.";
}
```

Comment: It is appropriate, Google "intel pause instruction".

Comment: The question is not about SpinWait behind-the-scenes mechanism But about its necessity in my **specific case**.

Comment: That's impossible to tell, use a concurrency analyzer.

Comment: Do you mean [Concurrency Visualizer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537632.aspx)?

Comment: @dadhi Just idea: Maybe to delay the threads in case of multiple conflicts?

Comment: @TN. May be you've got the point. BTW I am using this implementation for quite some time in DryIoc, and it works.